# JQuery animation to write a text using a pen

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery in my application.I want some text to be animated ie.,I want the text to be written(animated) when the page is loaded using an pen/pencil image in Jquery.

can anybody help me on this.

Comment: For future questions: there might be more interest in your questions if you accept some answers.

Answer (score 3):

Good luck with that. It isn't going to be easy!

I'd be looking at the canvas tag +  using a canvas based library such as processing.js http://processingjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

For this to really work properly you need the code to actually understand the shape of the glyphs that make up the font and then animate a pencil along those paths.

I'd suggest looking into RaphaelJS:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Here is a good example of the helvetica font broken into paths and animated (not quite the way you wanted though but a start)
http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html

It can register a font, convert the font to a path and you can animate a shape along that path so it's all there waiting to be tied together. You will end up tracing the edge of the letter so would trace the letter I down and up but if it is animated fast enough it should look pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Another (perhaps more easy) approach is actually to put a div above the text you want animated. The content of that div is the background color.

When the document is ready, you animated the div above the text to slide to the right, and you have a kind of text-write effect. It's not perfect, but worth the try if you don't have enough time.
Imagine the blue square below is the div above the text, being animated -> slide to right or width to 0.

[image: sliding text]